# Question about custom-made message

Tags: ros-kinetic, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I'm using ROS kinetic on ubuntu 16.04.

And I'm going to make my own message consisting of many sub-custom messages.

The sub-messages are in the right directory where any other messages are defined.

Below is a sample of the messages.

```
my_msgs/StateError          stateError              # error for state
my_msgs/EvalCovariance      evalCovariance          # validate covariance
```

and `my_msgs` is the name of the directory.
(In other words, `StateError` messages and `EvalCovariance` messages are all in the `my_msgs` directory.)

In this case, is it mandatory to drop `my_msgs`tags  because they're all in the same directory??
(like this)

```
EvalCovariance      evalCovariance          # validate covariance
StateError          stateError              # error for state
```

Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337326/question-about-custom-made-message/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2019-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

to define a message based on different messages (sub-messages) that are defined in same package you have two options:

1. you drop the package name before these messages because the sub-messages are defined in same package

> ```
> StateError         stateError
> EvalCovariance     evalCovariance
> ```

2. you indicate the `package_name` before these sub-messages  (not the `directory_name`) :

> ```
> package_name/StateError         stateError
> package_name/EvalCovariance     evalCovariance
> ```

so, if `my_msgs` is your package_name, both samples you wrote in the question are valid. But, if `my_msgs` is just a directory_name then you need to use the second sample without attaching `my_msgs/`

---

Originally posted by [mali](https://answers.ros.org/users/36867/mali/) with karma: 146 on 2019-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on 2019-11-12**:
Thank you so much for your short and clear advice. I really appreciate it.